# How to enhance the run speed of a function loop?

Tags: loops, google-apps-script

I am able to run the function below to find and replace a few cells at a specific Sheet and column, but I need to optimize the function so that I can reduce the completion time.

```
var r=ss.getDataRange();
var rws=r.getLastRow();
var j=8;
var i,a,find,repl;

function findReplace(find, repl, range) {
    find="alpha";
    repl="beta";

    for (i=1;i<=rws;i++) {
        a=r.getCell(i, j).getValue();
        if (r.getCell(i,j).getFormula()) {continue;}
        if (a==find) { r.getCell(i, j).setValue(repl);}
        try {
          a=a.replace(find,repl);
          r.getCell(i, j).setValue(a);
        }
        catch (err) {continue;}
      }
  };
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe store the the `r.getCell(i, j)` in a variable. You are calling it up to 4 times. Probably you can continue  `if (a==find) { r.getCell(i, j).setValue(repl); \*HERE*\ }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In the column "H", You want to replace the value of `find` to `repl`.

  - You want to replace the value of `find` to `repl`, when the value includes `find` and the value is the same with `find`.
- You want to ignore the formulas.
- You want to reduce the process cost.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several possible answers.

### Pattern 1:

In this pattern, the value is created in the loop, and the created value is put with `setValues()`. Before you use this script, please set the sheet name.

#### Modified script:

```
function findReplace() {
  const find = "alpha";
  const repl = "beta";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 8, sheet.getLastRow(), 1);
  var values = range.getValues();
  var formulas = range.getFormulas();
  var v = values.reduce((ar, row, i) => {
    row.forEach((col, j) => {
      if (formulas[i][j] != "") {
        ar.push([formulas[i][j]]);
      } else if (col.includes(find)) {
        ar.push([col.replace(find, repl)]);
      } else {
        ar.push([col]);
      }
    });
    return ar;
  }, []);
  range.setValues(v);
}
```

### Pattern 2:

In this pattern, TextFinder is used. Before you use this script, please set the sheet name.

#### Modified script:

```
function findReplace() {
  const find = "alpha";
  const repl = "beta";

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  sheet.getRange(1, 8, sheet.getLastRow(), 1).createTextFinder(find).replaceAllWith(repl);
}
```

### Note:

- Please enable V8.

### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))
- [Class TextFinder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/text-finder)

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the direction you want, I apologize.